# При попытке зарегистрировать бегунок gitlab появляется ошибка "Проблема с сетью"

Tags: gitlab, devops

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать runner под windows, после попытки присвоить runer тег в powershell появляется ошибка.

Выполняемая команда:

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
my-tag,another-tag
```

Текст ошибки:

> ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=uNqmWJVq status=404 Not Found
>   PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems

P.s. С инетом все нормально.

Разобрался что с тегами все нормально, текущая проблема такая:

Как определить/узнать свой gitlab-ci coordinator URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Это адрес компьютера на котором установлен сервер gitlab

```
https://gitlab.com
```

подробнее можете прочитать тут 
[Установка](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#windows)